I am struggling to define the space complexity of a turing machine
I have a problem where I have a class A which is made up of problems which is solveable with a TM with space complexity O(logn). I now need to prove that the problem, where an input string of length n has the equal amount of 0s and 1's is in A. I have decided to find a TM that can prove this is true, but I get stuck on finding the space complexity of this TM. If I were to prove that this TM would be in space complexity O(logn) would that work? Additionally could I get the space complexity of this TM by defining the total possible number of configurations?

Yes, if you can define such a TM that can solve the problem in space $O(\log n)$ that is sufficient to show that the problem is in class $A$. You should then prove that this TM never uses more than $O(\log n)$ space for any input of length $n$.
But I'm not sure I understand the second question; this TM must run through at least $n$ configurations in order to read its entire input (which is a necessary condition for solving the problem). So the number of configurations doesn't seem to help much with the space requirement. However, you can indeed prove that at each step $k$, it uses less $O(\log n)$ space (in fact, for this problem, you can design a TM that at each step $k$ uses $O(\log k)$ space).
